# arsort does not give the expected result

Tags: php, sorting, backticks

```
$a=array('a'=>'`a:1:`','b'=>'`a:`','c'=>'`a:0:`');
arsort($a);
print_r($a);
```

I expect this code to output

```
Array
(
    [a] => `a:1:`
    [c] => `a:0:`
    [b] => `a:`
)
```

but it actually outputs

```
Array
(
    [b] => `a:`
    [a] => `a:1:`
    [c] => `a:0:`
)
```

Do you understand why the backticks are messing up ?

Comment: The shorter string wins, no surprises here.

Comment: The backtick will be considered as character for sorting. As all start with one that is not an isuse but the length of strings is different so the last backtick is considered in your case. See example until after the `:` all values are the same, so next char is backtick, 1 and 0, and those are ordered reverse, which seesm correct to me.

Comment: oh that's damn right, I kept on considering the backticks as not part of the strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The backtick will be considered as character for sorting. As all start with one that is not an isuse but the length of strings is different so the last backtick is considered in your case. See example data, until after the `:` all values are the same, so the next chars to sort by are backtick, 1 and 0, and those are ordered reverse, which seems correct to me.

Giving my comment from above as answer, because I guess it's the right answer.

To extend it, you might need to do a uasort using `trim` to remove the backticks and sorting reversely then.